# How do I override javascript's cloneNode?

Tags: javascript, prototype

This is what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/beCVL/5/

This is how I'm trying to override the default cloneNode:
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "cloneNode", {
    get: cloneNode2,
    set: cloneNode2
});

but it's not working, so, I think Object.prototype doesn't have cloneNode, but Element.prototype doesn't either.

So, which class do I need to use to override cloneNode, assuming my method is correct?

Comment: `function cloneNode() { [native code] }` (in Chrome, at least) so I don't think you can really override it.

Comment: Well, I just need to override in Firefox, because cloneNode by default changes the color format in the style attribute to rgb from hex... which makes the clone not an exact copy.

Comment: It's still native code in FF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This series of fiddles is a work in progress, but it reimplements cloneNode's functionality. http://jsfiddle.net/beCVL/19/

as of April 4th, 10:53am EST, it needs to work with IE, as IE doesn't have a Node object.

Note, that in IE, prototype functions can't be overridden. So, all instances of cloneNode have to be replaced by a function that determines which version of cloneNode to use.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
Node.prototype.cloneNode = cloneNode2;
```

`Object.defineProperty` is not used for this purpose. Here's an example of a use for it:

```
var o = {};
Object.defineProperty(o, 'blah', {
    'get': function () { return 'asdf'; },
    'set': function (x) { alert(x); }
});

alert(o.blah); // alerts 'asdf'
o.blah = 'fdsa'; // alerts 'fdsa'
```

Apparently, this only works in Chrome.

To solve the actual problem, it should be simple enough to just replace the RGB codes with its equivalent hex code.

```
function decToHex(a) {
    return ('00' + (+a).toString(16)).substr(-2);
}
function replaceRGB(str) {
    return str.replace(/rgb\((\d{1,3}), (\d{1,3}), (\d{1,3})\)/, function (_, r, g, b) {
        return "#" + decToHex(r) + decToHex(g) + decToHex(b);
    });
}
replaceRGB("color: rgb(255, 0, 0)") // "color: #ff0000"
```

Comment: What do you expect it to do? If you add an `alert` to `cloneNode2`, it indicates it's using `cloneNode2` and not the native one (edit: in Chrome, at least)

Comment: Thought this technically works, it should be done on `Node.prototype` where it's actually defined. It wouldn't work if you had an instance of a Node that is not an Element (like a text node)

Comment: Ooops, Even though the doc says it's defined on Node https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.cloneNode, The browser seems to think it is defined on Element @TheLindyHop I'm pretty sure we determined it can't be done

Answer (score 0):

It's a property of `Node.prototype` https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.cloneNode

`Node.prototype.cloneNode = function() {}`

However, modifying built in objects may give you grief in the future. If possible, you should create a different function and use that instead, that way, existing code that uses `cloneNode` won't break.

Comment: @TheLindyHop  Which browser? It works for me in Chrome. I knew it wouldn't work in IE. I believe Chrome is the only browser that lets you modify it.

Comment: oh, Firefox. I don't need to override in the other browsers, because cloneNode in FF is broken.

Comment: That means it can't be done :( Btw, your clone node function doesn't properly set any attributes on the node itself, that is if your div contains any attributes, it won't be copied to the cloned node

Comment: @TheLindyHop I think outerHTML doesn't work in Firefox. The fiddle doesn't work in my version, though it is a very old version (3.6), it may work in newer versions